# The Resources class fails to load the theme into my app

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lwuit

I created a theme file called Theme.res and placed it in the same file as the .java file.
The Compiler simply seems to bypass that segment of code and the emulator displays the same B&W form as before without any of the applied font styles etc.

```
public void startApp() {
    Display.init(this);
    try {
        System.out.println ("print");
                  Resources r = Resources.open("/Theme.res");
        System.out.println ("print");
                  UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme("myTheme"));
         System.out.println ("print");
    } 
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        System.err.print ("lame"); 

    } 

    Form f = new Form();
```

only the first "Print" is actually printed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using Netbeans? In wich package is the Res?

Comment: yes. Its in the src file with HelloLWUIT.java.

Comment: is in the "deafult package"? Everything seems to be correct. Are you including LWUIT library?

Comment: It wasn't so I took it out if its package (which had a similar name to it) and put it in the 'default package'...and IT WORKS! Please can you make this suggestion as an official response to this question so I can vote and tick it. Also, why did it have to be in default package? why did it not work before in the other package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `Theme.res` in the default package and preserve the same path

Comment: It had to be in the default package because that is where the code you wrote is calling the theme from.